# How to import opencv2 framework in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, opencv, swift

I downloaded the latest pre-built opencv2.framework from the [OpenCV SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/2.4.9/).  then in Xcode6-Beta3, I added opencv2.framework as a required linked framework under the "General" tab of my Swift project settings:

[image]

This is the structure of the framework after the framework is added to the project:

[image]

If this was a Objective-C project I could add the following import statement:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

In my ViewController.swift file, if I do something similar I get a "no such module" error:

[image]

I tried the following variations that result in an error:

```
import opencv2/opencv.hpp
import opencv2/opencv
import opencv
import "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
import <opencv2/opencv>
```

What is the correct way to import opencv in to my Swift project?

Comment: I'm looking in to creating a bridging header to see if that works.  Try to figure out how to generate one in Xcode6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *will* need to create a bridge from C++ to Objective C or plain C. After that, you will need to include/import the bridge's header into an "Objective-C Bridging Header", which Xcode should have generated when you added a Swift source file in an existing project.

Answer (score 3):

It's easiest if you start with a simple project all ready to compile and run out of the box.

This xcode project works with Swift, XCode 6.1, OpenCV 2, and is MIT licensed:
http://whitneyland.com/2014/10/opencv-swift.html

Here's one I haven't tried yet but there are so few still it's worth looking at:
https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch